# Send an email from Google Spreadsheets when a value changes in a column & passes an IF test

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I want to create a Google Script to email me whenever a certain thing happens. I know how to create it but I can't figure out the code needed in the script.

1. The trigger is a combination of 2 things: cells in BU column change their values & the value of the corresponding row in the BV column is "nu".
2. The email should contain the following text:
   "Warning - [the corresponding row in the BW column] has written [the contents of the cell which was the trigger = in the BU column]."

I tried to look for answers but can't seem to crack this one. Please help.

Thanks

Here's the code I tried so far:

```
function sendEmailAlert() {

var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
var data = ss.getActiveSheet().getActiveCell().getA1Notation();
var sheetname = ss.getActiveSheet().getName();
var user = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
var Toemail = 'myemail@gmail.com';
var subject = 'Raspuns gresit Belbin';
var body = 'Cineva a raspuns gresit la testul Belbin - ' + ss.getUrl();

if(data.indexOf('BU:BU')!=-1.23456789) {

MailApp.sendEmail(Toemail,subject, body);
 }

};
```

Comment: Please provide some code that you've tried so far

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, please check [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), so you can help us to help you.

Comment: @Casper I added the code I wrote so far. Thanks for taking the time to help

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please summarise the searching and research that you have done - we wouldn't want to double up on that.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to have a function that runs every time a cell changes its value, you would need to use the [`onEdit()`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#onedite) function.

But, you wouldn't be able to send an email, as the [restrictions](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers#restrictions) say:

> They cannot access services that require authorization. For example, a
>   simple trigger cannot send an email because the Gmail service requires
>   authorization, but a simple trigger can translate a phrase with the
>   Language service, which is anonymous.

For more info about Event Objects, you can check [this](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/triggers/events).

As a plus, this code could help you to fulfill your goal, but taking into consideration the restrictions mentioned above.

```
function onEdit(e){
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();

  var range = e.range;
  var columnEvent = range.getColumn();
  var rowEvent = range.getRow();
  var bvColumn = // bv column number
  var buColumn = // bu column number

  var cellCondition = sheet.getRange(rowEvent, bvColumn, 1, 1).getValue().toLowerCase();

  if( columnEvent === buColumn && cellCondition === "nu"){
    // Do something here
  } 
}
```